# How to bulk delete the whole content (Files and Folders) of a library?

Tags: apex

I'm looking for a solution to delete all files and folders within a library or just the whole library itself in my Sandbox instance of Salesforce. I'm tired of deleting them manually via the UI.

I was able to delete all files with the library with this APEX script.

```
public static void deleteAllFilesInLibrary(String libraryName)
{
    Id idLinkedEntity = [SELECT Id FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = :libraryName LIMIT 1].Id;

    list<ContentDocument> listContentDocsToDelete = new list<ContentDocument>();

    for(ContentDocumentLink iterator : [SELECT ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =:idLinkedEntity]) {
        listContentDocsToDelete.add(new ContentDocument(Id = iterator.ContentDocumentId));
        system.debug('********ContentDocument.ContentDocumentId:' + iterator.ContentDocumentId);
        system.debug('********ContentDocument.Title:' + iterator.Title);
    }

    if(!listContentDocsToDelete.isEmpty() && listContentDocsToDelete != null) {
        system.debug('********contentDocumentIds:' + listContentDocsToDelete);
        system.debug('********contentDocumentIds.size:' + listContentDocsToDelete.size());
        Database.delete(listContentDocsToDelete, false);
        Database.emptyRecycleBin(listContentDocsToDelete);
    }
}
```

But it does not delete the folders so I still have to manually delete every folder before I can delete the library.

I'm not an experience APEX or Salesforce developer, so I need help here.
Every method I try ends up in an error message like this: "You can delete a Content Folder only if it's empty.". So how do I recursively delete all Content Folder?
Example: Library "Test_OLD" contains a folder "Test1". This folder "Test1" contains again a folder "Test2". How to delete the whole folder structure????

Can someone help me out here?

[image]

Comment: N.B. Pro Tip: `if(!listContentDocsToDelete.isEmpty() && listContentDocsToDelete != null) {` can be deleted, it serves no purpose. DML on empty collections works fine.  Have you looked at [FolderedContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_folderedcontentdocument.htm?q=contentworkspaceId)

Comment: @cropredy: Thanks for the pro tip. 
I do not understand how FolderedContentDocument can help me? I'm not an experience APEX or Salesforce developer, so I need more information here.
Every method I try ends up in the error message "You can delete a Content Folder only if it's empty.". So how do I recursively delete all Content Folder?
Example: Library "Test_OLD" contains a folder "Test1". This folder "Test1" contains again a folder "Test2". How to delete the whole folder structure????